# EC2 instance is running but cannot connect to it through curl or website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a running EC2 instance and have the pem key to it. However when I ssh into the instance run `curl localhost:` I get the following message:

500 Internal Server Error

## Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.

Please contact the server administrator at 
 ec2------.compute-1.amazonaws.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.

---

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I checked the Security groups and have added port 80. Where could I go to see more details on this error?

Comment: The message you are getting appears to come from the AWS console SSH client.  It's not very helpful to diagnosing the problem.  It might be worth attempting to SSH directly from your laptop with a client like Putty (if you are on MS Windows).  This might at least give you a more helpful error.

Comment: 500 Error is too general, please read you Apache web server logs for more information. The location of log file is at /var/log/apache2 directory